# Python: Regular Expressions on getting repeating set of numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, genbank

I'm working with a file, that is a Genbank entry (similar to [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Sitemap/samplerecord.html))

My goal is to extract the numbers in the CDS line, e.g.:

> ```
>     CDS             join(1200..1401,3490..4302)
> ```

but my regex should also be able to extract the numbers from multiple lines, like this:

> ```
>      CDS            join(1200..1401,1550..1613,1900..2010,2200..2250,
>                  2300..2660,2800..2999,3100..3333)
> ```

I'm using this regular expression:

```
     import re
     match=re.compile('\w+\D+\W*(\d+)\D*')
     result=match.findall(line)
     print(result)
```

This gives me the correct numbers but also numbers from the rest of the file, like

> ```
>  gene            complement(3300..4037)
> ```

so how can I change my regex to get the numbers? 
I should only use regex on it..

I'm going to use the numbers to print the coding part of the base sequence.

Comment: Is the join command part of the string? You could use the single line modifier, a lazy quantifier and a positive lookahead.

Comment: You just want to extract the number of complete line ? if numbers then in what format?

Comment: You would probably have a much much easier time parsing genbank files if you used [BioPython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.GenBank-module.html).

Comment: The join command is part of the string ,yes @Jan

Comment: I want the numbers, so that I can use them for printing out the elements in a list containing the base sequence @noob

Comment: @Gliz I'm confused, you're looking for numbers following `CDS`? So why don't you have `CDS` in your regex?

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit because the numbers can on many following lines, that don't contain CDS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the heavily improved [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module by *Matthew Barnett* (which provides the `\G` functionality). With this, you could come up with the following code:

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile("""
            (?:
                CDS\s+join\(    # look for CDS, followed by whitespace and join(
                |               # OR
                (?!\A)\G        # make sure it's not the start of the string and \G 
                [.,\s]+         # followed by ., or whitespace
            )
            (\d+)               # capture these digits
                """, re.VERBOSE)

string = """
         CDS            join(1200..1401,1550..1613,1900..2010,2200..2250,
                     2300..2660,2800..2999,3100..3333)
"""

numbers = rx.findall(string)
print numbers
# ['1200', '1401', '1550', '1613', '1900', '2010', '2200', '2250', '2300', '2660', '2800', '2999', '3100', '3333']
```

`\G` makes sure the regex engine looks for the next match *at the end of the last match*.
See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nM1fA4/1) (in `PHP` as the emulator does not provide the same functionality for `Python` [it uses the original `re` module]).

A **far** inferior solution (if you are only allowed to use the `re` module), would be to use lookarounds:

```
(?<=[(.,\s])(\d+)(?=[,.)])
```

`(?<=)` is a positive look**behind**, while `(?=)` is a positive look**ahead**, see [a demo for this approach on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mC0aQ8/1). Be aware though there might be a couple of false positives.

Comment: This looks awesome, but I don't think I'm allowed to use the regex module in my course :(. Is there something similar in the re module?

Comment: @Gliz You're not allowed to use the `re` module at all? Then why are you using it in your OP?

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit I'm allowed to use the re library ([this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)..) I might be confused, but there is a difference between re and regex module, right?

Comment: @Jan do you have any good reading for beginners on how to use assertions  ? I'm getting very close to what I want, but I think I need to understand assertions :)

Comment: @Gliz: You have plenty of options on the topic. A good starting point can be found [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), on [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/) (beginner to intermediate), on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (really buy the ebook!) and - my favourite - [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) (advanced to very advanced, maybe try the other ressources first).

Comment: @Jan great, thanks :) your inferior solution on one of my files is here: [link](https://regex101.com/r/mC0aQ8/3)

Comment: @Gliz: Really try to use the **far better** regex module if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

The following `re` pattern might work:

```
>>> match = re.compile(\s+CDS\s+\w+\([^\)]*\))
```

But you'll need to call `findall` on the whole text body, not just a line at a time.

You can use parentheses just to grab out the numbers:

```
>>> match = re.compile(\s+CDS\s+\w+\(([^\)]*)\))
>>> match.findall(stuff)
1200..1401,3490..4302       # Numbers only
```

Let me know if that achieves what you want!

Comment: I'm looping through each line in my file, and if I do that I get this output: ['     CDS             join(2424..2610,3397..3542)']

I'm only interested in the numbers :)

Comment: @Gliz If you want to match across multiple lines then looping through might not be the best idea. Obviously unavoidable though if your files are enormous! Are they too big to just read in one go? And even if you want just the numbers this is a good starting point, you can either continue to parse or use the `re` groups to pull them out (I'll add an example)

Comment: My biggest file is 1225 lines, about 5kb.. which is not much :p @HumphreyTriscuit

Comment: @Gliz In that case, just read it all at once rather than iterating through lines - does that work?